# How Can I Get Current Location on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager

I can't get current location. When I launch my app in different place, App can get last location. But I don't want to last location. If you close the app and restart it, now app can get current location. How can I get current location even if it is first launch of application?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    self.mapView.delegate = self;
    [self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];

    locationManager.delegate=self;

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    locationManager.delegate=self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.distanceFilter=kCLDistanceFilterNone;

    location = [locationManager location];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
    coord.longitude = location.coordinate.longitude;
    coord.latitude = location.coordinate.latitude;
    lat = coord.latitude;
    longt = coord.longitude;
}
```

Comment: [locationManager startUpdatingLocation]; put this line after setting delegate

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are doing `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];` before setting its delegate

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate=self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationManager.distanceFilter=kCLDistanceFilterNone;

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

And implement its delegate method

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
       didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

}
```

Comment: No you will have to wait for the `CLLocationManager` to tell you that a location has be determent.

Comment: You have given nice solution... ram ram sa aapne bhi.

Comment: Why alert for authorisation of getting location auto dismiss after 2 sec and I don't have any authorisation so delegates are not working? Any help?

Comment: @NaXir - ask question over SO, I will answer it..:)

Comment: Done. Now go ahead :)

Answer (score 0):

You should read the documentation provided in the [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/MKCoordinateRegion).

Specifically, when you ask for the current location, the system returns the last known location right away so you can do something useful with it. If you don't care about past locations, you can discard it and only use more recent location information by looking at the [`timestamp`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocation/timestamp) property of the `CLLocation` returned to determine how recent it is.

Answer (score 0):

You should really read the [`CLLocationManager`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) documentation.

Wat you are doing will not work, since it will take some time determine the device location.
Therefor you will need to wait until the `CLLocationManager` notifies you that a location has been determent.

You will need to implement the [`CLLocationManagerDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/CLLocationManagerDelegate) which will tell you if a location is determent or if the location determination failed.

Also you should also check if location can be determent with:

```
if ([CCLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
    // The location services are available.
}
```

You should also check wether you are authorize to use the location services with `[CCLocationManager authorizationStatus]`.