# WhatsApp like location sharing in iOS application

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps

I want to share user's current location from my iPhone application. And plan to show a preview screen of recieved location, like location sharing feature in WhatsApp application.

Is there any in-built functionality available with MapKit or Google Map in iOS.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no direct feature available (except whatsapp developers), but here's an idea to do this

1. Get user current location using `CLLocationManager` [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15265788/16032340)
2. Refer this, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/
3. You've to pass users latitude and longitude which you've to use to create static map image URL
4. Load that URL in `UIImageView` in background (something like, [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage))
5. You've to setup your required UI for this.