# How to get current location IOS device

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager, gmsmapview

I have been using GMSMap in my app. I want in my GMSMap user current location lat long. I am used lots of method but don't get current location. Please help and guid how to get my current location. I have read many tutorial and follow but don't get.

I have one question, I am using methods and any other work will be in my project? I am so tired please help.

Firstly I have write show bellow methods in my project then create IPA and install my device. But don't get current location latitude longitude.

Please help. Thankyou

## First

```
-(void)CurrentLocationIdentifier
 {
//---- For getting current gps location
locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
//------
 }
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
currentLocation = [locations objectAtIndex:0];
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init] ;
[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
 {
     if (!(error))
     {
         CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
         NSLog(@"\nCurrent Location Detected\n");
         NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark);
         NSString *locatedAt = [[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
         NSString *Address = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:locatedAt];
         _adrs_lbl.text = Address;
         NSString *Area = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:placemark.locality];
        NSString *Country = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:placemark.country];
         _lat_lbl.text = Country;

         NSString *CountryArea = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", Area,Country];
         NSLog(@"%@",CountryArea);
         _long_lbl.text = CountryArea;

     }
     else
     {
         NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error %@", error);
         NSLog(@"\nCurrent Location Not Detected\n");
         //return;
         //CountryArea = NULL;

     }

 }];
 }
```

## Second

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Location services are not enabled");
}
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];
self.latitudeValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", location.coordinate.latitude];
self.longtitudeValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", location.coordinate.longitude];
 }
```

## UPDATED QUESTION

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations{
currentLocation = [locations lastObject];
if (currentLocation != nil){
    NSLog(@"The latitude value is - %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude]);
    NSLog(@"The logitude value is - %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude]);
}
//Current
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:currentLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude: currentLocation.coordinate.longitude zoom:13];

self.mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
self.mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
self.mapView.delegate = self;
self.mapView.frame = viewDirection.bounds;
[viewDirection addSubview:self.mapView];

//    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
//    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, currentLocation.coordinate.longitude);
//    marker.title = @"Your Office Name";
//    marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"boss-icon.png"];
//    //OR
//    marker.icon = [GMSMarker markerImageWithColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
//    marker.snippet = @"Current Location";
//    marker.map = self.mapView;


GMSMarker *marker1 = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker1.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, currentLocation.coordinate.longitude);
marker1.icon = [GMSMarker markerImageWithColor:[UIColor redColor]];
marker1.title = @"my location";
marker1.snippet = @"City Name";
marker1.map = self.mapView;


GMSMarker *marker2 = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker2.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(22.6990,75.8671);
marker2.icon = [GMSMarker markerImageWithColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
marker2.title = @"Destination location";
marker2.snippet = @"City Name";
marker2.map = self.mapView;

NSString *originString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f",currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];

NSString *destinationString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f",22.6990,75.8671];

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%@&destination=%@&sensor=false",originString,destinationString];
NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:[str stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]]];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if(data == nil) {
        return;
    }else{
        NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        NSArray* latestRoutes = [json objectForKey:@"routes"];
        NSString *points=[[[latestRoutes objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"overview_polyline"] objectForKey:@"points"];
        _text.text = points;
        @try {
            // TODO: better parsing. Regular expression?
            NSArray *temp= [self decodePolyLine:[points mutableCopy]];
            GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath path];
            for(int idx = 0; idx < [temp count]; idx++){
                CLLocation *location=[temp objectAtIndex:idx];
                [path addCoordinate:location.coordinate];
            }
            // create the polyline based on the array of points.
            GMSPolyline *rectangle = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
            rectangle.strokeWidth=5.0;
            rectangle.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
            rectangle.map = self.mapView;

            [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
        }
        @catch (NSException * e) {
            // TODO: show erro
        }
    }
}];
[dataTask resume];

 [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

 }
```

[GMSMapView image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uDHa.jpg)

[Check my PolyLine IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZkCg.jpg)

Comment: Brother did you put some method in appdelagates file that ask user for location access and also did you put permission in .plist file ?

Comment: How please  explain?

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya Which methods to ask access location. please explain in some code.

Comment: [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]
[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]  use this

Comment: did didUpdateLocation  delegate method call?

Comment: I will help you want you want.

Comment: @user3182143 download my project and solve my problem. my problem is that location services call in AppDelegate then how to call in another view and how to automatic update lat long when user move to another place. my project link :   dropbox.com/s/mdwrpa72yf25ep4/map_poly.zip?dl=0

Comment: @user3182143 are you there? please reply

Comment: Yeah I am.I don't have device to check right now but I can help you.

Comment: Download and check my code. updated my project and solve my problem

Comment: what did you add in Plist for accessing location?

Comment: If you are patience tomorrow I will go office and check your code immediately and reply you.

Comment: ok no issue. Please remembered

Comment: Sure Tomorrow I make it for you.

Comment: ok thankyou so much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Can I Get Current Location on iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265755/how-can-i-get-current-location-on-ios)

Comment: @user3182143 Gud morning are you there, I am online please solve my problem. I am still waiting for your response. thankyou

Comment: I am going to my office.Once I reach,I will do.

Comment: Have reached? I am still waiting

Comment: Now I check your code

Comment: You have to change your code fully.

Comment: @user3182143 Full code? But i have no idea how to implement GMSMap in poly line  to another way. and update location when user move to another way.  please you can change.

Comment: I will post every line of code in answer.Follow each thing.

Comment: ok post line of code , I follow your every instructions.

Comment: I posted my answer please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give you the solution step by step

**STEP 1:**

> First we should get the
>    [Google Map SDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start)

**Drag the following bundles into your project (when prompted, select Copy items if needed):**

```
Subspecs/Base/Frameworks/GoogleMapsBase.framework
Subspecs/Maps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework
Subspecs/Maps/Frameworks/GoogleMapsCore.framework
```

**Right-click GoogleMaps.framework in your project, and select Show In Finder.**

**Drag the GoogleMaps.bundle from the Resources folder into your project. When prompted, ensure Copy items into destination group's folder is not selected.**

**Select your project from the Project Navigator, and choose your application's target.**

**Open the Build Phases tab, and within Link Binary with Libraries, add the following frameworks:**

```
GoogleMapsBase.framework
GoogleMaps.framework
GoogleMapsCore.framework
GoogleMapsM4B.framework (Premium Plan customers only)
Accelerate.framework
CoreData.framework
CoreGraphics.framework
CoreLocation.framework
CoreText.framework
GLKit.framework
ImageIO.framework
libc++.tbd
libz.tbd
OpenGLES.framework
QuartzCore.framework
SystemConfiguration.framework
UIKit.framework
```

**STEP 2:**

> [Get the API key](https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=maps_ios_backend&reusekey=true)

**STEP 3:**

```
Add the below things in your Plist    

  App Transport Security Settings   Dictionary 
  Allow Arbitrary Loads             Boolean          YES


  <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
  <string>RehabTask requires location services to work</string>

  <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
  <string>RehabTask requires location services to work</string>        

            OR

   Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description   string    RehabTask requires location services to work
   Privacy - Location Always Usage Description        string    RehabTask requires location services to work
```

Also you need to add

```
  <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
  <array>
     <string>googlechromes</string>
     <string>comgooglemaps</string>
  </array>
```

**STEP 4:** In appDelegate add below code

AppDelegate.m

```
@import GoogleMaps;
#import "AppDelegate.h"

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"AIzaSyCrCEb7qVkURIjq6jsfkPkwgN62sfj6Ff0"];
   return YES;
}
```

**STEP 5:**

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate,GMSMapViewDelegate>{
    CLLocation *currentLocation;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewDirection;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, strong) GMSMapView *mapView;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize viewDirection,locationManager,
@synthesize mapView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 10;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] == NO){
        NSLog(@"Your location service is not enabled, So go to Settings > Location Services");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Your location service is enabled");
    }
    if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
       [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate method
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations{
    currentLocation = [locations lastObject];
    if (currentLocation != nil){
        NSLog(@"The latitude value is - %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude]);
        NSLog(@"The logitude value is - %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude]);
    }
    //Current
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:currentLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude: currentLocation.coordinate.longitude zoom:13];

    self.mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    self.mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    self.mapView.delegate = self;
    self.mapView.frame = viewDirection.bounds;
    [viewDirection addSubview:self.mapView];

    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, currentLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    marker.title = @"Your Office Name";
    marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"boss-icon.png"];
                OR
    marker.icon = [GMSMarker markerImageWithColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    marker.snippet = @"Current Location";
    marker.map = self.mapView;


    GMSMarker *marker1 = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker1.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(22.7007,75.8759);
    marker1.icon = [GMSMarker markerImageWithColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    marker1.title = @"Place Name";
    marker1.snippet = @"City Name";
    marker1.map = self.mapView;


    GMSMarker *marker2 = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker2.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(22.6990,75.8671);
    marker2.icon = [GMSMarker markerImageWithColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    marker2.title = @"Place Name";
    marker2.snippet = @"City Name";
    marker2.map = self.mapView;

    NSString *originString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f",22.7007,75.8759];

    NSString *destinationString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f",22.6990,75.8671]; 

    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%@&destination=%@&sensor=false",originString,destinationString];
    NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:[str stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
    NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if(data == nil) {
            return;
        }else{
            NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
            NSArray* latestRoutes = [json objectForKey:@"routes"];
            NSString *points=[[[latestRoutes objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"overview_polyline"] objectForKey:@"points"];
            @try {
                // TODO: better parsing. Regular expression?
                NSArray *temp= [self decodePolyLine:[points mutableCopy]];
                GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath path];
                for(int idx = 0; idx < [temp count]; idx++){
                    CLLocation *location=[temp objectAtIndex:idx];
                    [path addCoordinate:location.coordinate];
                }
                // create the polyline based on the array of points.
                GMSPolyline *rectangle = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
                rectangle.strokeWidth=5.0;
                rectangle.map = self.mapView;
                [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
            }
            @catch (NSException * e) {
                // TODO: show erro
            }
        }
    }];
    [dataTask resume];
    }
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}

//I called below method in above temp(NSArray *temp = [self decodePolyLine:[points mutableCopy]]) for Drawing route between two or more places
-(NSMutableArray *)decodePolyLine: (NSMutableString *)encoded {
    [encoded replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\\" withString:@"\\"
                                options:NSLiteralSearch
                                  range:NSMakeRange(0, [encoded length])];
    NSInteger len = [encoded length];
    NSInteger index = 0;
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] ;
    NSInteger lat=0;
    NSInteger lng=0;
    while (index < len) {
        NSInteger b;
        NSInteger shift = 0;
        NSInteger result = 0;
        do {
            b = [encoded characterAtIndex:index++] - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        NSInteger dlat = ((result & 1) ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;
        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = [encoded characterAtIndex:index++] - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        NSInteger dlng = ((result & 1) ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;
        NSNumber *latitude = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:lat * 1e-5] ;
        NSNumber *longitude = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:lng * 1e-5] ;
        printf("[%f,", [latitude doubleValue]);
        printf("%f]", [longitude doubleValue]);
        CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[latitude floatValue] longitude:[longitude floatValue]] ;
        [array addObject:loc];
    }

    return array;
}

@end
```

Happy Coding :-)

Comment: No need to add.

Comment: I think add one more line in this code ` rectangle.strokeColor`

Comment: apply same code in your code and add UIView(viewDirection) as outlet property in your code.That is enough.

Comment: You don't need to add rectangle.strokeColor.If you just follow the above steps you can get the output.I used key in above API key.There is everything.Don't add any extra thing in your code,

Comment: In the direction url I mentioned your lat,long values also.

Comment: This is your direction API URL http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=22.700700,75.875900&destination=22.699000,75.867100&sensor=false and It gives full response including route points

Comment: Above is your direction  API URL.Check it in browser.It gives everything.

Comment: Do you want to connect the path or draw the route between these places?

Comment: That is everything in above code.I mentioned all things in above.It draws the path.

Comment: same one but it I called decodePolyline method in NSArray *temp= [self decodePolyLine:[points mutableCopy]] line.

Comment: Check your code with iPhone or iPad real time device.Don't check with simulator.

Comment: Distance between swadesh nagar and Panchavati is 183.5 kms or 114 miles or 99.1 n miles

Comment: Check with nearby lat,long values first.I mean 5km or 10 km distance.

Comment: NO NO distance only 2-3 km

Comment: Send me your project now I will check.

Comment: panchavati red sign is my device location and green sign is destination location (swadesh nagar).

Comment: I am downloading.Once it finishes I will check and tell you.

Comment: Please check with your nearby lat, long values. and your current location to draw a path.

Comment: I checked and ran the code now.It shows route between my current place to destination place.Also the code is correct.

Comment: No any changes in my project? and show routs? with my API key?

Comment: No changes in your code.Everything is fine.It shows routes between current and destination also api key is correct.

Comment: But in my device do not show polyLine? why? please check with teamViewer. Please I am still stuck this module. please help?

Comment: My TeamViewer ID is `317 204 474` and password `8gu98i` please access and see where I am wrong. You connected after show my device via quick time player. please last time help me. please

Comment: Are you there? Please sir help me. please :(

Comment: I can't  use  TeamViewer at my office.Your code works perfectly.

Comment: Now again create IPA and install in my device than open app. But show only my location and destination location. Not show the path connected to both location.

Comment: But here I can get the route between current and destination location through your project.

Comment: Then do one thing.Increase your view height and remove auto layout.Reduce the textview height.

Comment: This url is correct - NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/direc‌​tions/json?origin=%@‌​&destination=%@&sens‌​or=false",originStri‌​ng,destinationString‌​]

Comment: I again check and Implement in my view. after i tell you

Comment: You got the solution.Check it slowly.First be cool.You got the solution and you can get the result.

Comment: Increase viewDirection height and decrease the textView height.Also remove or uncheck the box of auto layout.

Comment: I checked your code with iPad.Just I changed your destination lat,long value to my lat,long value.It shows route correctly from my current place to destination place.

Comment: Use this url only - http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=22.700700,75.875900&destination=22.699000,75.867100&sensor=false

Comment: That is wrong.Use NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%@&destination=%@&sensor=false",originString,destinationString]; only

Comment: Exactly NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/direc‌​tions/json?origin=%@‌​&destination=%@&sens‌​or=false",originStri‌​ng,destinationString‌​];

Comment: your accordingly I used your URL. I have only iphone 5s device. and I check also Create IPA then ran in device. because my device not connected to directly system.

Comment: Switch On the location service in your iPhone from Settings.

Comment: Ok again i checked and I try ones more. Then create any problem I am telling you. :)

Comment: You got the output finally.I see your result from your images..That's it.

Comment: Always on location service in my setting. but same issue.

Comment: Dont worry I accepted your answer but PolyLine not getting in my device. Please firstly solve my problem and then sure get the up vote for your answer. please trust me.

Comment: My answer is not for drawing polyline.it is for drawing route between places.

Comment: but not draw PolyLine in my device?

Comment: Also your question is getting current location only.

Comment: Your answer is only show the places not draw a PolyLine between two places?

Comment: sir please suggest how to show polyline in my device? I am so tired :(

Comment: Here I can see the route(red color line) If I run your code.

Comment: I edited my answer.You need to add App Transport Security Settings in Plist.Now I check with iPhone5s.I got same result that what you got.Once I added Arbitrary loads to YES it shows route.I added App Transport Security Settings in Plist in above answer.

Comment: It Works works works if you add App Transport Security Settings dictionary in your Plist.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134420/discussion-on-answer-by-user3182143-how-to-get-current-location-ios-device).

Comment: @user3182143 Yes draw a polyLine. but not proper draw. That time different- different place to start polyLine. That means device location some time wrong and some time correct. why?

Comment: In your  response you got everything an decodePolyline method draws the  route from points.It doesn't draw route anything wrong.Check Your internet connection properly.If you have proper internet connection it shows exct route.

Answer (score 0):

Add following lines in your info.plist

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>App required location because it is needed when .... </string>
```

Also check that you added following line in your code

```
if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
    {
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by others in their comments, you need one or 2 keys in your info.plist, and you need to ask the user for permission to use the GPS. See this link for the code:

[Checking location service permission on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153074/checking-location-service-permission-on-ios)

The link below lists the keys you need to enter into your info.plist and the code you need, but the code is in Swift:

http://nshipster.com/core-location-in-ios-8/